# Short story about man travelling in universe that changes every few hours

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cold-war

Trying to find a short story I read around 20 years ago.

Probably from the 60s/70s, it's about a man in the Cold War, shot in an experimental rocket that goes into hyperspace or something. It specifically mentions that society in America is now pretty much the same as the USSR - the USSR not being able to win the Cold War outright, but have succeeded in making USA into a controlling surveillance society.

It turns out that the universe is very unstable and changes every couple of hours. As he was out of the universe when it changed the man is the only person who moves with it. He meets a people who zap him with a ray gun so that he speaks their strange guttural language. They know all this, and know they've only existed for an hour and will vanish in an hour.

The universe keeps changing, the man essentially becomes God, and he recreates the world he comes from. The stinger is that everyone now speaks in the weird language of the people who explained what was happening to him.

Any ideas you might have about who wrote it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may have mixed [this story about time travel and the language bit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107417/what-time-travel-story-required-the-traveller-to-mentally-reconstruct-his-worl) with something else.

Comment: This is definitely the story! Thank you very much. I need to see what I've mixed up. Strange, I've read quite a bit of Moorcock and didn't recognise it as one of his.

Comment: I think I did conflate the Cold War stuff from another story but yes this is almost exactly as I remembered it. Trying to work out which of my dad's old collections it was from. Hi,
you started me off in the right direction! I found stackexchange which is a forum where people ask these very kind of questions.

The story is "flux" by Michael Moorcock. Funnily enough I own "The Best of" Michael Moorcock and the short story obviously wasn't considered one of his finest and doesn't appear there.

Comment: "making USA into a controlling surveillance society" sounds like real life.

Comment: That's what I thought too! The Moorcock story ahs a lot of social satire but it's about the European Economic Community (forerunner to the EU) - which as a Brit made me sad after Brexit.